# Multiple NSURLConnections in different classes running parallel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsrunloop

Currently I have UITableView and simple UIView in my iPad application. Each of them needs to get data from remote Web-service simultaneously. In each ViewController I create NSURLConnection and run a request to web service, but it seems that second one never return nothing at all.

Is it possible to run two separate requests in parallel?

What I found so far is an advice to use `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];` though I am not sure how to use it in this context :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is. In one of my apps I do concurrent downloads using NSURLConnections without problem.

Comment: @onnoweb: the question of "whether is it possible" implies "if so, how?" :)

Comment: @WASD42 you should expand your question to include what you have tried so far. Did you try +connectionWithRequest:delegate: ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuuuuu!

My bad, I forgot to instantiate the response NSMutableData variable. AGAIN! :)

Thanks everyone for your attention!